# How to read a Hex editor file

Tags: python, hex-editors

I have some data (electrical currents and time) and I used Hex Editor to erase the header for Python to read it.

I want to work with the raw data in Python. Let's say, in the original data I have (`200pA, 1 ms; 300pA, 2 ms` just for an example). The Hex editor encode it. But I want to have the original data (`200pA, 1 ms; 300pA, 2 ms`) again in Python.

I used:

```
with open (rb"C:\Users\cguev\Desktop\Mar02a01_noheaer.D20", encoding="ASCII",errors="ignore") as d:
    data=d.read()
print(data)
```

This is a part of the converted file:

ÝvUm¹v\mÙvTmÛvOmïvPmÑvQmÏv\mãvSmÃvVmív

But I don't know how to get the decimal data again.

Comment: This is a section of it: vUmv\mvTmvOmvPmvQmv\mvSmvVmv[mvYmvRmvVmvUmvZmvXmwUmvUmvSmvQmvUmvQmvOmvUmvYmvSmvVmvSmvXmv]mvRmvWmwYm

Comment: This is a part of the output: b'\xddvUm\xb9v\\m\xd9vTm\xdbvOm\xefvPm\xd1vQm\xcfv\\m\xe3vSm\xc3vVm\xedv[m\xd1vYm\xccvRm\xe5vVm\xe3vUm\xd2vZm\xe3vXm\x02wUm\xc7vUm\x8evSm\xe4vQ